# Does specifying the OutAttribute on ByRef internal methods currently do anything?

Tags: vb.net, out, byref

VB.NET doesn't have `out` parameters, but you can specify `<Out()> ByRef` on COM and P/Invoke methods to get the same effect for external methods.

Does specifying the same on internal methods (i.e. methods only called by .NET code) actually help the Jitter (or VB.NET compiler)? Or is it currently only useful as a programmer note.

Is it possible it could be used in a future Jitter, or is this attribute lost when compiling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've confirmed a VB.NET `<Out()>` does cause a C# client to require `out` arguments, so it does seem to be effectively the same.

Also a C# client passes in its arguments with current values into the method, but that's not surprising because, unlike the COM or P/Invoke cases, there's no marshalling to do. (And C# won't allow a property to be set by an `out` argument directly, so there doesn't seem to be a way to see if C# would optimise away a previous unneeded assignment.)

So it seems the answer is it does help possible future C# clients use the code, and if the jitter ever adjusts the C# equivalent, it would do the same here. Though because languages like VB exist, it can't do much because they don't respect the [`Out` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx) themselves.

Comment: Yes, it is *exactly* the same. The C# `out` keyword compiles down to IL code that contains the `<Out()>` attribute. VB.NET just doesn't have the keyword. You can verify this for yourself by compiling two test projects and using ILdasm to compare them.

Comment: I'm assuming this refers to the Out attribute in namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices. Is that the case?

Comment: @jswolf19 Yes, modified, also in my answers in linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

I subclassed `MembershipProvider` with a VB class, we'll call it A,  and then subclassed A with a C# class we'll call B. The C# code, B, was not recognizing the fact that the abstract methods in the `MembershipProvider` had already been implemented in the VB subclass, A,  until I applied the `OutAttribute` in the VB class for parameters that were specified as `out` in the `MembershipProvider` base class abstract methods.  This  has an impact beyond just COM or P/Invoke.