# C# and VB.Net out parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net, parameters, out

I've got a project in c# which is making use of another project written in vb.net. I am currently able to modify both.

I've got a method in the VB project like:

```
    Public Sub MethodName(ByVal param1 As String, ByRef param2 As String)
        param2 = param1 + 1
    End Sub
```

I am not able to call this method using the out keyword from C#:

```
    public void CallOtherMethod()
    {
        string param1 ="test";
        string param2;

        provider.AddTransaction(param1, out param2);
    }
```

Shouldn't the ByRef keyword in VB.Net have the capabilities of both "ref" and "out"?

Should I just go with ref?

Comment: My guess would be that `out` is the same as `ref` with an additional attribute, while `ByRef` is just `ref`.

Comment: A ref parameter needs initialising, but I don't need or have any use for that. I'm not really asking this because I'm stuck, I can easily go with using ref.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a VB.NET equivalent of C# out parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358742/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-of-c-out-parameters)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To the runtime `ref` and `out` are fairly interchangable, as they are both just passing a reference. *However*, `out` is prefixed with an additional attribute in the IL:

```
public void y(ref int a)
public void z(out int a)
```

turns into

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  y(int32& a)
.method public hidebysig instance void  z([out] int32& a)
```

which enables the C# compiler to distinguish the two *and* add the special semantics that `out` has, namely that an `out` parameter does not need to have an assigned value before entering the method and *must* be assigned a value before exiting the method.

In contrast, `ByRef` in VB only provides `ref`, but not the additional semantics of `out`. There it no equivalent of `out`in VB.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in my [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744173/does-specifying-the-outattribute-on-byref-internal-methods-currently-do-anything/6760527#6760527) you *can* specify an [`<Out()>` attibute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx) on the parameter definition and, although VB ignores it, C# treats the argument correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent of `out` in VB (to my knowledge.) Just `ByRef` which is an equivalent of `ref` so that would be the correct choice.

Since you will be **passing** by reference the called function will recieve your value and you will need to intialise you parameter so that it has an address in memory.

EDIT:

Since you can edit both, why not change the `Sub` to a `Function` and get rid 
of the problem altogether and, IMO, make your code nicer too.

Comment: I've got more than one parameter that needs returning in my actual project. I asked this question just for the sake of learning rather than a solution for my project.

I'll just go with ref. Cheers.

Comment: You could return a class or structure. Just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Go with `ref` - it's the C# equivalent for VB's `ByRef`.

**BUT**
Read this detailed explanation: [When to use ref vs out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out/1516890#1516890).