# SHGetInstanceExplorer function returns E_FAIL

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, com, windows-shell-extension-menu

When I try to use the **[SHGetInstanceExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function, it returns an `E_FAIL` **HRESULT**

I've defined these two functions with differents parameters (to test them), both definitions returns the same error:

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
Private Shared Function SHGetInstanceExplorer(
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByRef ppunk As Object
) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
Private Shared Function SHGetInstanceExplorer(
    ByRef ppunk As stdole.IUnknown
) As Integer
End Function
```

I'm not really sure which kind of components more than a *shell ext.* are allowed to use this feature, I tried it from a *WinForms* application, maybe the problem is that?.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use the function? It reads like the kind of thing you do if you're implementing a shell extension with some kind of background work going on. That doesn't sound like a good fit for a Winforms project.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe It is actually for the purest curiosity, I not yet managed to find an applicable helpful case for a WinForms project, however, I tried to use that function for curiosity to discover whether a child process having that reference can avoid to be killed when parent process is killed with a signal to kill child processes too, but the function returns E_FAIL so I can't test my absurd things.

Comment: Which instance of explorer would you expect to be returned? It's not as if your WinForms process is hosted by Explorer. It would seem that `E_FAIL` is precisely what would be expected.

Comment: To add to what @DavidHeffernan says - `SHGetInstanceExplorer` seems to be a utility function added so Shell extensions can access the browser instance as a kind of global static. Until and unless you instantiate a shell browser in your process there will not be an instance to return.

Comment: The documentation you linked to says "Retrieves an interface that allows hosted Shell extensions and other components to prevent their host process from closing prematurely." It is for plug-ins to extend the lifetime of the process they are running in. It sounds like you are attributing magical powers to it that aren't written in the documentation.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Yes, you are right, my fault all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `<Out>` attribute along with `ByRef` since VB.Net doesn't have `out` keyword as in C#.

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
Private Shared Function SHGetInstanceExplorer(
    <Out()> ByRef ppunk As stdole.IUnknown
) As Integer
End Function
```

- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shgetinstanceexplorer
- [Is there a VB.NET equivalent of C# out parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358742/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-of-c-sharp-out-parameters)