# Unable to cast object of type 'DataSourceDefinition' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: vb.net

Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetDataSourceContents2": 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SqlServerProject2.webservice.DataSourceDefinition' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
System.InvalidCastException: 
   at SqlServerProject2.UserDefinedFunctions.GetDataSources2(String Datasourcename)
.

I get the above error while running the clr function from the below vb.net assembly. Can someone help?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports SqlServerProject2.webservice
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Partial Public Class UserDefinedFunctions

<SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName:="FillRow")> _
Public Shared Function GetDataSources2(ByVal Datasourcename As String) As IEnumerable

    Dim WS = New ReportingService2005
    WS.UseDefaultCredentials = True

    Dim DSContents As DataSourceDefinition = WS.GetDataSourceContents(Datasourcename)

    Return DSContents

End Function

Public Shared Sub FillRow(ByVal obj As Object, <Out()> ByRef ConnectString As SqlString)
    Dim DSContents As DataSourceDefinition = CType(obj, DataSourceDefinition)
    ConnectString = New SqlString(DSContents.ConnectString)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I guess that you have used the `FillRow` example from somewhere like [CLR Table-Valued Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4). VB.NET does not have the `Out` keyword: [Is there a VB.NET equivalent of C# out parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4358742/1115360). If you used [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it would have pointed out that problem for you.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for responding. I removed the <Out> keyword from subroutine, but get the same error when trying to run the function. Program errs out when trying to convert DataSourceDefinition type to IENumerable type, tried with both implicit & explicit conversions. This conversion is required to pass on values to FillRow sub.

Comment: I don't have my code example from experimenting to hand or the time to re-create it, but [Basics of Using a .NET Assembly in MS SQLServer - User Functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28429/Basics-of-Using-a-NET-Assembly-in-MS-SQLServer-Use) may give you enough clues to be getting on with.

Comment: OK, I found my experiment, but I wrote it in C#. ISTR that I had to add the [SqlFunctionAttribute.TableDefinition Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.tabledefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it work. The code you show would use `<SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName:="FillRow", TableDefinition = "ConnectString nvarchar(128)")>` (of course, adjust the type as appropriate). I could be wrong.