# VB.Net Roslyn Insert Statement before current function call

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I am using the SyntaxWalker to go through a tree and in the function below I realize I need to insert a statement before the one I am working on.

```
Public Overrides Function VisitDeclarationExpression(ByVal Node As CSS.DeclarationExpressionSyntax) As VisualBasicSyntaxNode
    Dim VariableDesignation As CSS.SingleVariableDesignationSyntax = CType(Node.Designation, CSS.SingleVariableDesignationSyntax)
    Dim name As NameColonEqualsSyntax = Nothing
    Dim value As ExpressionSyntax = CType(VariableDesignation.Accept(Me), ExpressionSyntax)
    ' Need to Insert Dim before the statement that contains this SimpleArgument 
    Return SyntaxFactory.SimpleArgument(name, value)
End Function
```

I need to declare "name = Nothing" so I can use name in a TryGetValue(name). In C# it would be easy using

```
return v.TryGetValue(out var name)
```

but in VB I need two statements

```
Dim name As Object = Nothing
Return v.TryGetValue(name)
```

How do I insert the Dim above the statement I am in the middle of walking?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem right, but...VB automatically initialises all local variables in a method, so you can use ByRef without needing to explicitly initialise the variable first. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358774/5688800

Comment: The variable doesn't exist (the statement is only the second line shown in the example), I need to create it and until some future release of VB you get a warning about use of uninitialized variable even thought the function being called declares the parameter as <Out>