# Equivalent of inline out parameter declaration?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Had a search and can't find this.

I'm looking for the VB.Net equivalent of C#7 inline out variable declaration, e.g:

```
MethodCall(arg1, out string arg2);
```

Does such a thing exist in the equivalent VB.Net versions?

*** the duplicate proposed isn't quite right I'm afraid, but I've marked Heinzi's answer correct.**

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/whats-new-in-visual-basic-15.html) this wasn't included in VB 15 so there's no equivalent yet

Comment: In VBnet you have ByValue and ByRef.  So ByRef is the closest to out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a VB.NET equivalent of C# out parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358742/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-of-c-sharp-out-parameters)

Comment: @Bouke: It's not a duplicate: The question you linked to asks about out parameters in general, this one asks about *inline variable declaration*, i.e., the `string` part of `out string arg2`.

Comment: To most of the commentators (except Camilo & Heinzi): Read the post! The C# code example is a method call which is declaring the 'out' variable right there where it's used.

Comment: @jdweng I think you missed the point of the question ... it's not about passing arguments by reference or value - or about finding an equivalent to out parameters, but about the _inline declaration_ available in C#7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature has been suggested to the Visual Basic language team:

- [Proposal: inline variable declaration and assignment within expressions.](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/159)

but it is currently not implemented.